# Can motor run capacitors be used in high frequency applications?

Tags: capacitor, rf, frequency

What, if any, problems would arise when using motor run capacitors in circuits operating in higher frequency ranges?   Such as 2000 to 10,000 Hz or 10 to 100 kHz

As they are only intended to run in 60 Hz applications, I'm wondering if internal resistance would become noticeable and cause excessive heating or if some other potential issue will arise. **What is the range of internal inductance on a motor run capacitor?** That would surely be more noticeable at higher frequencies.

*I'm considering such capacitors for my application because of their large capacitance and modest voltages at a low price point.*

Comment: Most capacitors are limited by dV/dt and a motor start capacitor does not have to handle large dV/dt so as you go up in frequency, this will be the limit at some point. tan fi heating comes to mind too. How much voltage swing at high frequency do you need?

Comment: Start capacitors and run capacitors are quite different beasts. I'd expect run capacitors to be fine across the audio range, and their inductance to become important as you approach RF frequencies. Best way to be sure would be testing. Start capacitors, with much higher capacitance ... I'd be doubtful about them.

Comment: @winny I'm expecting voltage swing of 100volts peak to peak but I may be able to accomplish the task with as little as 40volts

Comment: @winny what is tan fi heating?

Comment: @Jim tan fi heating is when the high frequency causes heating within the dielectric of the capacitor (ever wondered how nonmetallic objects are heated by microwaves... same process)

Comment: 100 volt peak to peak out of how much voltage rating on the capacitor in the first place? What's the dV/dt limit of the capacitor in the first place?

Comment: @winny The problem is that motor run capacitors often don't have that kind of information available because they aren't intended for a purpose other than running a motor.   However,  after reading the comments I did further reading about Q factor, Esr,  and dv/dt and I found out that good quality motor run capacitors typically work fine for audio range applications.   The dissipation factor in that range is often only 0.1%.   It should work excellent.

Comment: It could work fine. I would be worried about your 100 Vpk-pk @ 100 kHz.

Comment: If you can tell us the exact application you are thinking of, we could give you more useful advice. As @winny said, 100Vpp@100kHz is (generally speaking) quite unusual (outside maybe motor applications). Moreover other characteristics of your application may play a role for the suitability of those caps.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.  The basic construction isn't too different from a high frequency capacitor -- a roll of film and foil (or metallization) -- except in termination: typically, a pair of foil connections are welded/crimped into the electrodes, in the middle of the winding.  So you're up against the ESR and ESL of those flimsy connections, as well as the ESL (and ESR to a lesser extent) of the total length of the windings.  Whereas, typical film capacitors (not in oil cans) have metallization applied to both ends of the winding -- shorting across the entire length of each electrode.

Offhand, I would guess, if you limit the RMS current to a similar value as nominal, it will work fine.  But this doesn't leave many VARs as you go up in frequency, and the ESL and ESR will frustrate applications like SMPS filtering.

---

Proper high power, high frequency capacitors, I think are made in a number of ways; similar to dipped/boxed types, but... more.  And often incorporating heatsink plates, bus bars or water cooling tubes.

One style, I think, uses a hollow winding (i.e., the film is wound around a core, which is later removed), passing a connection to the far end through the center.  The connectors then look like a donut (near face), and a plate with a rod sticking out the middle.  Thus a coaxial sort of connection can be had, with ESL dominated by the length of that middle connection.  The middle can be solid, or made of hollow tubing for cooling water.

Another style, just uses "cells" made in the usual way -- usually around an inch or few across, not too big so as to keep the thermal path short (there's also a skin effect to mind, which incentivizes small cells).  The cylindrical windings are metallized at both ends (schoopage), then tinned, and soldered between bus bars.  Many in parallel are used to make up the total value.  Cooling pipes can be soldered/brazed onto the bars, and the whole assembly can be hermetically sealed inside a metal can, making connection through bolted terminals with plastic or ceramic seals.

So, quite different from the simple, loosely connected designs used at mains frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

3 things may limit the usefulness of these capacitors:

1. Rather high ESR, parasitic inductance and loses. Motors generally don't care about things like ESR. Your proposed application may as well depend on these parasitics to be lower. The capacitor may heat more than intended.
2. Non-linearity. Their capacitance depends on voltage and polarity. Motors don't care much about this either.
3. Limited range of voltages. Most of these are rated for about twice the single-phase utility voltage in your area. 3-phase motors don't use them so you are limited to 450V (in 230V world) or 250V (in Edison's bad decisions burdened part of the world)

Answer (score -1):

You get what you pay for. Using 60Hz caps on a 3kHz (example) supply will shorten the life of the insulation by roughly 50x (ie 100k hour design gets reduced to 2k hours at same rated voltage). Not only that but most line frequency caps are cheap paper/foil/oil. Low loss at 60Hz but that quickly gets lossy at kHz frequencies if voltage isn't reduced. You might get away with it for low duty cycles and/or voltages but if it heats up enough you can turn the metal can into an unintentional pipe bomb. Then there's the parasitic problems you mentioned. Personally I'd just spend the extra cash for proper caps (sounds like you need metallized pp film ones) rather than risk it.

Comment: It sounds like you’re saying that capacitors are good for a certain number of charge/discharge cycles - can you cite a source for this?  Datasheets for electrolytics often quite a higher ripple rating at switch-mode frequencies than for 100Hz.